# Prevent auto background sizing to full line width header text

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve the following using CSS on my `<h1>` element (since  apparently it is not default browser behaviour):

[image]

However, I can't seem to keep my browser from rendering it as following:

[image]

Does anybody have an idea how to achieve this properly?

**Current code:**

```css
.title {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 68px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 58px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #000;
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1>This is a title on two lines</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`display: inline` instead of `inline-block`

```css
.title {
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
  line-height: 68px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.title h1 {
  font-size: 42px;
  line-height: 58px;
  color: #FFF;
  background: #000;
  white-space: normal;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  display: inline;
  vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="title">
  <h1>This is a title on two lines</h1>
</div>
```